Is the white man at the other side of the Joliba river a historically identifiable person?
Maryse Condé's novel Ségou: les murailles de terre (1984; translated into English as Segu) contains both fictional characters (presumably the entire Traoré family) and historical characters. Some of the historical characters are easily identifiable, whereas others aren't. For example, in the first chapter, many inhabitants of Ségou run to the Joliba / Niger river because they have heard there is a white man on the other side who wants to visit the city. Since the river is 300 meters wide at that point, they don't see what they were hoping for.
The request to visit the city is important enough for the royal council to discuss it. Eventually, they don't allow the man to visit Ségou. None of the characters named in the novel meet him and his name is not mentioned. Could this be a reference to a real event? After all, there were many white explorers in Africa during the period in which the novel is set, i.e. beginning at the end of the 18th century.

Yes, within the text the identity of the white man was found by Samuel Adjai Crowther, the close friend of Eucaristus (one of Naba's sons):

"Oh, I nearly forgot!"' said Samuel suddenly. "You remember that story
you kept telling me, about a white man who was at the gates of Segu
when your father was born? Well, I know who it was... It wasn't an
evil spirit, an albino, or whatever. It was a Scot called Mungo Park."

Later in the book, Eucaristus finds and reads the book that Mungo Park wrote about his travels, including his visit to Segu, Travels in the Interior Districts of Africa performed under the direction and patronage of the African Association in the years 1795, 1796, and 1797 by Mungo Park, Surgeon.

In chapter 3 of the book, the seer Mori Zoumana makes the following suggestion to mansa Monzon Diarra:

Send a messenger to the white man. Tell him that, wishing to help him, who is so far from his country, you are sending him a bag of five thousand cowries in order to buy provisions. Tell him also that he can use the services of your messenger as a guide to Djenné, if he intends to go there. But do not allow him to enter Ségou.

The first few chapters are set in 1797, at the time when Mansong Diarra was mansa of Ségou. The Wikipedia article about Mansong Diarra mentions that Mungo Park "passing through the Bambara capital of Ségou in 1797".
In his Travels in the Interior Districts of Africa: Performed Under the Direction and Patronage of the African Association, in the Years 1795, 1796, and 1797 (1799) Mungo Park wrote that he arrived at bank of the Niger river opposite Ségou on 20 July 1797 but (page 197)

the king could not possibly see me, until he knew what had brought me into his country; and that I must not presume to cross the river without the king's permission.

There were no messages on 21 July. On 22 July, a messenger came to ask whether Park had brought any presents for the king, but Park had earlier been robbed by the Moors. On 23 July, there was another messenger (page 199):

In the afternoon, another messenger arrived from Manson, with a bag in his hands. He told me, it was the king's pleasure that I should depart fortwith from the vicinage of Sego; but that Mansong, wishing to relieve a white man in distress, had sent me five thousand Kowries, to enable me to purchase provisions in the course of my journey: the messenger added, that if my intentions were really to proceed to Jenné, he had orders to accompany me as a guide to Sansanding.

